# File Removes take forever in Mercurial

Tags: performance, mercurial

We recently migrated to Mercurial and, on the whole, the performance is dramatically better than its predecessor (Vault). One thing that is very slow though, is *file deletions*.

If someone pushes a changeset with a lot (~1000) of deletions, subsequent pulls take forever (up to an hour over VPN). [hg up takes  awhile too, but that seems like a different question]. Most of the time is consumed with network I/O

Two part question:

1. Have other sites experienced this?
2. Any suggestions for how to ameliorate the problem?

Our central repo is hosted on Windows Server 2003 behind IIS. The users have various flavors of windows.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm an Hg dev)

Your experience is very puzzling, there are no reason why that would happen. Deletions are mostly free and shouldn't trigger a large amount of network IO.

Are you sure there's nothing else ? Can you try creating a bundle of the changes to get an idea of the size?

Comment: I will create a bundle and see what is in it.